# R: AUC from pROC package

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, roc, auc

I recently came across `pROC` package to get `AUC`. In the help section, they give following example:

```
library("pROC")
data(aSAH)
auc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
```

In above, `outcome` is a `factor` whereas `s100b` is `numerical`.

My question is how does `AUC` work in this case? What threshold does it apply for `s100b`? Or it does not matter?

**Edit 1**
The above code results in `AUC = 0.73`. How do I know which threshold value was chosen to get this value?

Comment: Per the docs: "When it is called with two vectors (response, predictor) or a formula (response~predictor) arguments, the `roc` function is called and only the AUC is returned." I'm not sure what you mean by thresholds, `auc` is calculated by default using all thresholds between 0 and 1. You can also check ?roc for details as well.

Comment: @zack thanks for your response. I have added more information. Basically, what determines the output of AUC.

Comment: You sound a little confused; as @zack says, AUC is calculated across all possible thresholds. Maybe my answer here would be helpful: [Getting a low ROC AUC score but a high accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104129/getting-a-low-roc-auc-score-but-a-high-accuracy/47111246#47111246).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AUC in the [`auc`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/auc) function of pROC is the Area Under the [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). Behind the scenes the function calls the [`roc`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/roc) function first, and so what you did is equivalent to:

```
myroc <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
auc(myroc)
```

The ROC curve is obtained by calculating sensitivity and specificity for all possible thresholds. You can visualize the curve with the [`plot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/plot) function, and the AUC is shown in grey:

```
plot(myroc, auc.polygon=TRUE)
```

[image: A ROC curve with the AUC displayed in grey]